# Extracting the ref from the forwardRef (createRef compared to useRef) | react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to us react-native-share in order to share an image which is a view in my app (using ViewShot), this doesn't really matter.

I have used it successfully for a while when I used useRef to get the ref of the view I want to share. When printing current.props.children I see:

```
<ShareQRImage prop1="..." />}
```

which is the view that I want and this works well.

Now I can't use useRef because I am not in a functional component. I want to export the ref. I am using createRef for the image. I get the ref but when printing current.props.children I get:

```
<ForwardRef(Image) source={172} />
```

What I want to get at this point is

```
<Image source={172} />
```

How do I get this from the forwardRef?

Comment: https://itnext.io/reusing-the-ref-from-forwardref-with-react-hooks-4ce9df693dd

Answer (score -1):

forwardRef is your missong part of view!
this code snippet from reactjs.org may help you:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```